# How to print invoice on roll paper using html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, invoice

I want to print my page on roll paper using html and javascript but it is not printing the way i want to . Here's my code.
I used css to make it print on roll paper size. but not worked.

[the output i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2W2d.png)

[the output i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80GIH.png)

I have given the screenshot of the print page

I tried everything but it didn't work .

**HTML**

```
  <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">

        <div class="container mt-5 mb-3 inv" style="width:290px;">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card" id="section-to-print">
                        <div class="p-1 text-center">
                            <h6 style="font-size: 18px"><b>
                                    {{ $user->company_name }}
                                </b></h6>
                            <b class="nine">
                                {{ $user->company_address }}
                            </b><br>
                            <b class="nine">ग्राहक सेवा क्र.

                                {{ $user->mobno }}


                            </b>
                        </div>

                        <hr class="hr__class" style="background:black; height:.1px;" />
                        <div style="margin-top: -10px;">
                            <b class="five ml-3">दिनांक :
                                {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($fposmaster->created_at)->format('d-m-Y') }} </b>

                            <b class="five ml-4">वेळ
                                :{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($fposmaster->created_at)->format('H:i') }} </b> <br>
                            <b class="five ml-3">बिल क्र.{{ $fposmaster->invoice_no }} </b>
                            <b class="five" style="margin-left:55px;">Operator : 1 </b>
                            <br />
                            <b class="five ml-3">नाव : @if (isset($data[0]->name))
                                    {{ $data[0]->name }}
                                @else
                                    Walking Customer
                                @endif
                            </b>
                            <b class="five ml-4">Type :{{ $fposmaster->type_bill }}</b>
                        </div>

                        <table class="mx-auto mt-2">
                            <tr class="five">
                                <th>क्र.</th>
                                <th>वस्तूचे नाव</th>
                                <th>वि.किं.</th>
                                <th>आपला दर</th>
                                <th>रक्कम</th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        {{-- Start foreach loop from here --}}

                        @foreach ($data as $count => $item)
                            <span class="list_ ml-3 mt-1 pt-1">{{ $count + 1 }} ) {{ $item->english_name }} /
                                {{ $item->marathi_name }}</span>
                            <span class="list_" style="margin-left:35px;"> {{ $item->product_qty }}<span
                                    class="ml-2">{{ $item->unit_name }}</span>
                                
                                <span class="mx-2"> &#8377;.{{ $item->mrp }}</span> <span
                                    class="ml-2">&#8377;.{{ $item->product_price }}</span>
                                <span
                                    class="ml-2">&#8377;.{{ $item->product_qty * $item->product_price }}</span></span>
                            </span>
                        @endforeach

                        <hr />
                        <div class="text-center ">
                            <p style="font-size:9px; margin-top:-10px !important;">एकूण : <b class="ml-2"> &#8377;

                                    <?php
                                    $total_two = 0;
                                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                                        $total_two = $total_two + $data[$i]->mrp * $data[$i]->product_qty;
                                    }
                                    echo $total_two . '/-';
                                    
                                    $total_ = 0;
                                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                                        $total_ = $total_ + $data[$i]->product_price * $data[$i]->product_qty;
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </b></p>

                            <p style="font-size:9px; margin-top:-10px !important;">आपली बचत : <b class="ml-2">
                                    &#8377;
                                    {{ $total_two - $total_ }} /-
                                </b>
                                @if ($data[0]->discount_amt != 0)
                                    <p style="font-size:9px; margin-top:-10px !important;"> सूट : <b style="font-size:15px"
                                            class="ml-2"> &#8377;
                                            {{ $data[0]->discount_amt }} /-

                                        </b></p>
                                @endif
                            <p style="font-size:9px; margin-top:-10px !important;">एकूण बेरीज : <b style="font-size:15px"
                                    class="ml-2"> &#8377;
                                    {{ $data[0]->total_bill }} /-

                                </b></p>
                                <hr/>
                                @if(isset($data[0]->multipay_credit_amount))
                                @if ($data[0]->multipay_credit_amount)
                                <p style="font-size:8px; !important;">उधारी येणे : <b
                                    class=""> &#8377; {{ $data[0]->multipay_credit_amount }} /-</b> दिनांक : {{ $data[0]->multipay_credit_return_date }}
                                </p>
                                <hr/>
                                @else 
                                @endif
                                @endif
                               
                            @if (isset($reward_points))
                                <p> <strong>Reward Points : </strong> {{ $reward_points }} </p>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        @if ($customer_group == null)
                        @elseif($data[0]->customer_group == "Mart")
                        <center>Reward</center>
                        <table class="table-bottom mx-auto mt-2" style="">
                            <tr class="table-two-fonts">
                                <th>OLD</th>
                                <th>CURRENT</th>
                                <th>TOTAL</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-two-fonts text-center  tr-">
                                <td>{{ $data[0]->reward_old }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $data[0]->reward_current }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $data[0]->reward_old + $data[0]->reward_current }}</td>
                            </tr> 
                        </table>
                                @elseif($data[0]->customer_group == "Card")
                                <center>Savings</center>
                        <table class="table-bottom mx-auto mt-2">
                            <tr class="table-two-fonts tr-">
                                <th>OLD</th>
                                <th>CURRENT</th>
                                <th>USED</th>
                                <th>TOTAL</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-two-fonts text-center  tr-">
                                <td>{{ $data[0]->total_savings }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $data[0]->current_savings }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $data[0]->multipay_used_savings_amount }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $data[0]->total_savings + $data[0]->current_savings - $data[0]->multipay_used_savings_amount }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table> 
                        <br />
                        <center>Reward</center>
                        <table class="table-bottom mx-auto mt-2" style="">
                            <tr class="table-two-fonts">
                                <th>OLD</th>
                                <th>CURRENT</th>
                                <th>TOTAL</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-two-fonts text-center  tr-">
                                <td>{{ $data[0]->reward_old }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $data[0]->reward_current }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $data[0]->reward_old + $data[0]->reward_current }}</td>
                            </tr> 
                        </table>
                        @endif
                    <br />
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                            @if ($user->qr_code)
                                <img src="{{ asset('uploads/qr_code/' . $user->qr_code) }}" alt="{{ $user->qr_code }}"
                                    width="70px" class="pl-2" alt="">
                            @else
                                <P> QR code</P>
                            @endif
                            <p class="nine mt-4 text-center ml-2">ऑनलाइन पेमेंट साठी <br /> स्कॅन करा</p>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <p class="nine text-center">धन्यवाद परत भेट द्या. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
 <style>
        @media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #section-to-print {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
        .inv {
            font-size: 11px !important;
        }

        .nine {
            font-size: 9px
        }

        .five {
            font-size: 6px;
        }

        .list_ {
            font-size: 8px;
            font-weight: bold
        }

        hr {
            margin-top: 5px !important;
        }

        .table-bottom,
        .tr- {
            border: 2px solid white;
        }

        table tr {
            border: .5px solid black;
        }

        table tr th {
            padding: 5px !important;
        }

        .table-two-fonts {
            font-size: 9px !important;
        }

    </style>
```

Comment: Have you tried `#section-to-print {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0
  }`

Comment: @raaahad I did. but not worked. Same output

Comment: Its working for me. Try to resize container on print to full width

Comment: No sir its not working for me . Can you share the screenshot ??

Comment: @swapnilmane Are you able to provide your compiled HTML? You can go into devtools and edit <body> as HTML and then paste it in a code block in your question

Answer (score 0):

The following should make your `#section-to-print` fill the entire receipt area:

```css
.section {
  border: 10px solid dodgerblue;
}

@media print {
  #section-to-print {
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    inset: 0;
    border: 10px solid coral;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section" id="section-not-to-print">
  <h1>Section not to print</h1>
</div>
<div class="section" id="section-to-print">
  <h1>Section to print</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working sir. @Zach Jensz

Comment: @swapnilmane I'll open up a browser and test it, give me a few minutes to fix it

Comment: @swapnilmane It's probably easier to use the `inset` property, see if that works with your code